# Defining global (dynamic) variables in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, global-variables

Is there a way of defining a dynamic global variable in Codeigniter?  I need to regularly use:

`$this->session->userdata('user_id')`

in my code, and I really don't want to have to type this out all the time.  What I've done in another project is use something like:

```
$this->mid = $this->session->userdata('user_id')
```

in a controller's constructor, making it accessible for every method in that controller, but I then have to redefine it in every other controller constructor.  I know I sound lazy, but I just want to make the best DRY code possible.  I know you can specify static variables in the config/config.php file, but these variables are dynamic - so I don't think you'll have access to the $this object (or something) in that file.

Is there anyway of making such a session variable global?

Comment: Introducing globals just to be more DRY is like smashing your car's windows to save the time to open them. But since you are using  CI already I am sure there is some base class you can stick it into.

Comment: Yeah, I found a solution: either define them in the core Controller.php's constructor, or make your own MY_Controller and extend the base class. Thanks for the hammy simile though.

Comment: Please create an answer and mark it as accepted so this doesn't show up in unanswered lists any more. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom controller MY_Controller.php:

```
<?php
    class MY_Controller extends Controller {

        var user_id = '';

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();

            $this->user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        }
    }
?>
```

And extend that controller by your controllers, for example the controller Welcome.php:

```
<?php
    class Welcome extends MY_Controller {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function index() {
            var_dump( $this->user_id );
        }
    }
?>
```

You can set the global variable in MY_Controller and use it on every controller that extends the custom one.